# Does a linked list ever have a lower amortized run-time complexity than a vector?

Tags: linked-list, time-complexity, amortized-analysis

Are there any situations where a linked list allows for a lower run-time complexity than the amortized time for using (and occasionally "rebuilding") a vector?

For example, a naive analysis shows that in the worst case, `push_back` is O(1) on a linked list and O(n) on a vector.  However, if the vector doubles every time it resizes, the amortized time for `push_back` is also O(1).

Are there cases where the amortized time of using a vector can't be reduced to that of the linked list?

Comment: Do you mean, are there operations on a linked list which are asymptotically faster than the same operations on a dynamic array?

Comment: Yes, but with sequences of operations, not just individual operations.  I know that in individual insert with a linked list is asymptotically faster than an individual insert in a vector.  But, is there an algorithm requiring many inserts that is asymptotically faster with a linked list than with any combination of dynamic array operations.

Comment: Well, the complexity of a sequence of operations is just the sum of the complexities of the individual operations, whether those are amortised or not. So for any operations that are faster on a linked list than a dynamic array, an algorithm using those operations will be faster on a linked list than a dynamic array. But usually when there is a difference, the algorithm is designed to use a particular data structure and the analysis assumes that data structure; e.g. binary search is O(log n) on an array but not on a linked list.